# How get data null relations in related Tucker-Eric / EloquentFilter

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I created EloquentFilter using Tucker-Eric/EloquentFilter

But I have problems with filter data that has nullable relation

```
    public function docs(String $status)
    {
        $status = filter_var($status, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
        if(boolval($status) === true) return $this->related('doc', 'user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
        return $this->related('doc', function($query) {
            return $query->where('user_id', '!=', Auth::user()->id);
        });
    }
```

this code return only data with not null relation
but supposed that in 'false' it will return data with nullable relations and data that doesn't have Auth::user()->id

Answer (score 0):

I find only one way to solve it

```
    public function docs(String $status)
    {
        $status = filter_var($status, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
        if(boolval($status) === true) return $this->related('doc', 'user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
        return $this->has('doc', '<', '1') ?: $this->related('doc', function($query) {
                return $query->where('user_id', '!=', Auth::user()->id);
        });
    }
```

Comment: In this, `$this->has('doc', '<', '1')` will always be true because it returns another query builder instance and the other condition will never be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to return all `doc` that doesn't have `user_id` when the `$status` is `false` then the following will allow it:

```php
public function docs(string $status)
{
    $status = boolval(filter_var($status, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN));

    if($status === true) {
        return $this->related('doc', 'user_id', Auth::user()->id);
    }

    return $this->related('doc', function($query) {
        return $query->whereNull('user_id');
    });
}
```